# What kinds of types does qsort not work for in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting, generic-programming, qsort, move-semantics

`std::sort` swaps elements by using `std::swap`, which in turn uses the copy constructor and assignment operators, guaranteeing that you get correct semantics when exchanging the values.

`qsort` swaps elements by simply swapping the elements' underlying bits, ignoring any semantics associated with the types you are swapping.

Even though `qsort` is ignorant of the semantics of the types you are sorting, it still works remarkably well with non-trivial types. If I'm not mistaken, it will work with all standard containers, despite them not being POD types.

I suppose that the prerequisite for `qsort` working correctly on a type `T` is that `T` is /trivially movable/. Off the top of my head, the only types that are not trivially movable are those that have inner pointers. For example:

```
struct NotTriviallyMovable
{
    NotTriviallyMovable() : m_someElement(&m_array[5]) {}

    int m_array[10];
    int* m_someElement;
};
```

If you sorted an array of `NotTriviallyMovable` then the `m_someElement`s would end up pointing to the wrong elements.

My question is: what other kinds of types do not work with `qsort`?

Comment: I find the use of the tag `move-semantics` a little bit confusing here, as it is usually associated with C++0x's move semantics.

Comment: Basically it is undefined behavior to use `qsort` for any non POD type in C++. From there on, the specific cases for which it will break and how is not that important: you should not use it anyway.

Comment: Why would you want to use `qsort` in the first place? On all platforms I've checked, `std::sort` was faster (for trivially-swappable object types), and that is completely plausible, given the option of inlining the comparison operator.

Comment: the last time I measured `std::sort` was about twice as fast because it sorted in place (no memory allocation). With C++0x we even get move constructor for free for most types, and thus swap becomes as good as bit-copying... when it's safe. So why would you bother, at all, with `qsort` ?

Comment: @Christopher @Matthieu: One good reason is because of code bloat. Last time I checked, each unique usage adds around 5KB of code. In code that isn't on a hot path, it would be better to have smaller code rather than faster code. Also, even in hot paths, it could be better to use qsort so that you get better I-cache usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work either for types that have pointers to "related" objects. Such pointers have many of the issues associated with "inner" pointers, but it's a lot harder to prove precisely what a "related" object is.

A specific kind of "related" objects are objects with backpointers. If object A and B are bit-swapped, and A and C pointed to each other, then afterwards B will point to C but C will point to A.

Answer (score 5):

Any type that is not a POD type is not usable with `qsort()`. There might be more types that are usable with `qsort()` if you consider C++0x, as it changes definition of [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Modification_to_the_definition_of_plain_old_data). If you are going to use non-POD types with `qsort()` then you are in the land of UBs and daemons will fly out of your nose.

Comment: That's not true. For example `std::vector` simply has a pointer to external data and swapping the underlying bytes will maintain all its invariants. Admittedly it's a bit 'hacky', but it will work if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Peter: You are completely mistaken. Doing this is way more than just 'hacky' or using implementation-specific behaviour- it's flat out undefined.

Comment: @DeadMG: There's a big difference between what the standard says is undefined and what compilers do in practice. For example, the extremely popular Fast Delegates library (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx) is riddled with technically undefined behaviour, but is used (and works) nonetheless.

Comment: @Peter Alexander: The difference is that those implementations cannot change behaviour on a whim. He depends upon aspects of the implementation that are, in practice, well-defined, if not in letter. You, on the other hand, are just praying, and any implementation could change, well, pretty much any aspect of itself, and horrifically break what you're doing and stay conforming.

Comment: Even a type as "simple" as `std::string` become non-trivial when you have smart implementations with things like the small-string optimizations. Those may very well have pointers into the `std::string` itself.

Comment: @Peter Alexander: When we are talking POD, we are talking POD of the contained type, not POD-ness of the container. You can use `qsort` to order the elements of a `std::vector` that contains POD types.

Answer (score 1):

You are completely mistaken. Any non-POD type working with `qsort` is complete and utter luck. Just because it happens to work for you on your platform with your compiler on a blue moon if you sacrifice the blood of a virgin to the Gods and do a little dance first doesn't mean that it actually works.

Oh, and here's another one for not trivially movable- types whose instances are externally observed. You move it, but you don't notify the observer, because you never called the swap or copy construction functions.

Comment: For external observers, that won't work even if you use `std::sort` (unless the object being sorted /knows/ about its external observers).

Comment: @Peter: It was implied that in the copy/swap functions of your type, you would notify them.

Answer (score 1):

"If I'm not mistaken, it will work with all standard containers"

The whole question boils down to, in what implementation? Do you want to code to the standard, or do you want to code to implementation details of the compiler you have in front of you today? If the latter, then if all your tests pass I guess it works.

If you're asking about the C++ programming language, then `qsort` is required to work only for POD types. If you're asking about a specific implementation, which one? If you're asking about all implementations, then you've sort of missed your chance, since the best place for that kind of straw poll was C++0x working group meetings, since they gathered together representatives of pretty much every organization with an actively-maintained C++ implementation.

For what it's worth, I can pretty easily imagine an implementation of `std::list` in which a list node is embedded in the list object itself, and used as a head/tail sentinel. I don't know what implementations (if any) actually do that, since it's also common to use a null pointer as a head/tail sentinel, but certainly there are some advantages to implementing a doubly-linked list with a dummy node at each end. An instance of such a `std::list` would of course not be trivially movable, since the nodes for its first and last elements would no longer point to the sentinel. Its `swap` implementation and (in C++0x) its move constructor would account for this by updating those first and last nodes.

There is nothing to stop your compiler switching to this implementation of `std::list` in its next release, although that would break binary compatibility so given how most compilers are managed it would have to be a major release.

Similarly, the map/set/multimap/multiset quartet *could* have nodes that point to their parents. Debugging iterators for any container might conceivably contain a pointer to the container. To do what you want, you'd have to (at least) rule out the existence of any pointer into the container in any part of its implementation, and a sweeping statement like "no implementation uses any of these tricks" is pretty unwise. The whole point of having a standard is to make statements about all conforming implementations, so if you haven't deduced your conclusion from the standard, then even if your statement is true today it could become untrue tomorrow.

Comment: For the record, I have a list implementation that works exactly like Steve's description. The "link" part of the linked list is separated from the data, and `list_node` and `list_head` (without a data member) both inherit from the link part. The `list_head` is embedded in the list object itself to save a dynamic allocation. The `list_head`'s swap function and move constructor adjust the pointers of the first and last list element so they follow the `list_head`'s movement. This wouldn't work with qsort!

Comment: I don't actually care about the standard containers, I was just using them as an example of non-POD types that could probably be swapped by exchanging bytes. My question was asking what kinds of types it would not work for, not whether it would work for the standard containers.

Comment: Your question is: "what other kinds of types don't work?". My answer is, "among other things, standard containers".